# Which of the following is not required while you are developing a bean?

Tags: java

i got this question in an interview, and i am confused about the correct answer, so please  advise.

Which of the following is not required while you are developing a bean ?

1. Implementation of serializable.
2. Default constructor.
3. Introspection ability.
4. Delegation model.
5. Implementation of SingleThreadModel

Comment: Is this about java beans or EJBs?

Comment: @Cratylus, i have no idea the question was not specific but i guess it was talking about EJB

Comment: @Charles, is it forbidden to ask about interview questions here ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, not exactly; a while ago, the community came to a consensus that there was no need to *tag* interview questions as such.  The question still needs to be practical and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, a default constructor is required as well as getters/setters (aka accessors/mutators) for all bean properties, which facilitates introspection.

It also says they should be serializable.  I am not sure how much to read into the use of "should", but I'm not surprised.  I have seen many non-serializable beans.  But I honestly do not know if that is legal or not.  You'd have to check the spec to be certain.  I would recommend serializability wherever possible.

However, I have never heard of SingleThreadModel or delegation model.  So I think the correct answer would be that the last 2 items are not required.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans